# Japanese keyboard layout (JIS) missing in Ubuntu 18.04, strange Alt behavior

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, japanese

I have a standard Japanese keyboard (JIS) in my laptop.

[image: Japanese laptop keyboard photo]

but this layout does not appear in `Settings > Region & Language > Input sources`. 
All of them seem to have the following configuration:

[image: Ubuntu Japanese keyboard layout]

Moreover when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> on the left side (<kbd>Alt L</kbd>) it has strange behavior; when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> on the right side (<kbd>Alt R</kbd>) it behaves normally. For example I cannot navigate in Nautilus with the <kbd>Alt L</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> key. In general it seems that <kbd>Alt</kbd> triggers a menu.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Then select the keyboard you have, if you don't see it in the list, General 105 is okay.
 Select Japanese then also it asks the AltR behaviour, too.